# Mongoose not accepting an enum schema when extracted

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a simple Schema

```
  export const CycleSchema = new Schema({
    enum: [
      "once",
      "weekly",
      "bi-weekly",
      "monthly",
      "trimester",
      "semester",
      "yearly",
      "custom",
    ],
    type: String,
  });

  const offerSchema = new Schema<IMongooseOffer>({
    customCycle: Number,
    cycle: CycleSchema,
  })
```

That throws the error:

```
offer validation failed: cycle: Cast to Embedded failed for value "once" (type string) at path "cycle" because of "ObjectExpectedError"
ValidationError: offer validation failed: cycle: Cast to Embedded failed for value "once" (type string) at path "cycle" because of "ObjectExpectedError"
    at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3170:32)
    at model.$set (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1463:12)
    at model.$set (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1117:16)
    at model.Document (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:164:12)
    at model.Model (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:123:12)
    at new model (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4718:15)
    at C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2929:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\node_modules\.pnpm\mongoose@7.5.3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2918:30)
    at OfferDao.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zhamd\work\UserCredits\src\impl\mongoose\dao\BaseMongooseDao.ts:34:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

If I write it like this it works:

```
  const offerSchema = new Schema<IMongooseOffer>({
    customCycle: Number,
    cycle: {
      enum: [
        "once",
        "weekly",
        "bi-weekly",
        "monthly",
        "trimester",
        "semester",
        "yearly",
        "custom",
      ],
      type: String,
    },
  })
```

I need to export and reuse CycleSchema, so I'm wondering what to do. Nothing on the web apart [ObjectExpectedError](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/api.html): Thrown when you set a nested path to a non-object value with strict mode set.